# Spark: ERROR LiveListenerBus: Listener EventLoggingListener threw an exception

Tags: apache-spark

I executed a spark program in which I am applying Drools rules on fact object using customer framework. I am calling this custom framework with in Flatmap function and rule was executed successfully but after collecting the result I saw the below exception. 
    Has anyone faced the same issue ? How can I fix this error ? Please help me on this issue.

```
15/09/18 10:45:34 INFO JDBCRDD: closed connection
15/09/18 10:45:34 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0). 599 bytes result sent to driver
15/09/18 10:45:34 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 3405 ms on localhost (1/1)
15/09/18 10:45:34 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
15/09/18 10:45:34 INFO DAGScheduler: Stage 0 (collect at SMAAlertImpl.java:84) finished in 3.425 s
15/09/18 10:45:34 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: collect at SMAAlertImpl.java:84, took 3.719422 s
15/09/18 10:45:35 ERROR LiveListenerBus: Listener EventLoggingListener threw an exception
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener$$anonfun$logEvent$3.apply(EventLoggingListener.scala:144)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener$$anonfun$logEvent$3.apply(EventLoggingListener.scala:144)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.logEvent(EventLoggingListener.scala:144)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.onStageCompleted(EventLoggingListener.scala:165)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerBus$class.onPostEvent(SparkListenerBus.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.onPostEvent(LiveListenerBus.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.onPostEvent(LiveListenerBus.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus$class.postToAll(ListenerBus.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus.postToAll(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1617)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1.run(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:60)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.checkOpen(DFSClient.java:792)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.flushOrSync(DFSOutputStream.java:1998)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.hflush(DFSOutputStream.java:1959)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.hflush(FSDataOutputStream.java:130)
        ... 19 more
15/09/18 10:45:35 ERROR LiveListenerBus: Listener EventLoggingListener threw an exception
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener$$anonfun$logEvent$3.apply(EventLoggingListener.scala:144)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener$$anonfun$logEvent$3.apply(EventLoggingListener.scala:144)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.logEvent(EventLoggingListener.scala:144)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.onJobEnd(EventLoggingListener.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerBus$class.onPostEvent(SparkListenerBus.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.onPostEvent(LiveListenerBus.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.onPostEvent(LiveListenerBus.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus$class.postToAll(ListenerBus.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus.postToAll(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1617)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1.run(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:60)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.checkOpen(DFSClient.java:792)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.flushOrSync(DFSOutputStream.java:1998)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.hflush(DFSOutputStream.java:1959)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.hflush(FSDataOutputStream.java:130)
        ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Able to fix the error by adding sc.close() . (sc - SparkContext)

Comment: Where did you make the change?

Comment: This would be at the end of the Spark script, which I assume the OP wrote in Python. It's not fixing it for me, but I'm not sure if the error even matters for me. Hard to test because the error seems to appear randomly and rarely in my workflow.

Comment: you sure it's `sc.close()` not `sc.stop()`? I can't seem to find this `close()` function at all

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have the "FileSystem.close()" action, because the spark will use the same FileSystem to write logs, so don't close it.

Answer (score 2):

Setting spark.eventLog.enabled to false "resolved" the problem for me since calling sc.close() after a failed action (e.g. "count") in a Spark Shell is not helpful.

I also changed the config option spark.scheduler.listenerbus.eventqueue.size from default of 10,000 to 500,000, but that alone did not solve my problem.

Sources:

http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/EventLoggingListener-threw-an-exception-when-sparkContext-stop-td23580.html

https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/14269